# List with all cryptocurrencies available in the GOOGLEFINANCE formula?

Tags: google-sheets, google-finance

I tried to find some documentation on what cryptocurrencies are retrievable with the GOOGLEFINANCE formula, but I couldn't find any. There's only [this general helpsheet](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093281?hl=en) on the topic, which doesn't mention cryptos at all.

Comment: Would you please summarise your research prior to posting this question.

Comment: @Tedinoz I googled it but found nothing. I don't mean this in a bad way, but the standards for posting a question in this community are extraordinary stringent. I view the robustness of the SE format (votes, moderation, tagging) and the SEO ranking of the website as solid arguments for accepting more questions, in spite of them lacking a three-paragraph body.

Comment: Since you specifically mentioned GOOGLEFINANCE, have you looked at this [Finance Data Listing and Disclaimers](https://www.google.com/googlefinance/disclaimer/#) - it is hyperlinked from the "helpsheet" page.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I haven't, but it only lists Coinbase as the apparent provider for cryptocurrency data. It's not an exhaustive list of all pairs.

Comment: `GOOGLEFINANCE` using the "Currency" code does appear to work with  BTC, ETH, BCH, and LTC